# How to set icon size for childs on parent widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating a widget where I want to set the the size of the icons used in the sub-widgets globally.

```
class ItemsContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Item> items;
  final double iconSize; //global default

  const ItemsContainer({
    @required this.items,
    this.iconSize = 56.0,
  });
}

class Item {
  final Icon icon;

  const Item ({
    @required this.icon,
  });
}
```

What  I'd like to do is this:

```
for (var item in items) {
  if (item.size == null)
    item.size = iconSize;
}
```

The problem I face is, that I can't set the size due to the fact, that I have a const constructor.

I could clone an existing Icon and change the original size, but is there a better way to do it?

```
Icon _getSizedIcon(Icon icon, double size) {
  return icon.size != null ? icon :
    Icon(icon.icon,
      size: size,
      color: icon.color,
      key: icon.key,
      semanticLabel: icon.semanticLabel,
      textDirection: icon.textDirection,
    );
}
```

Comment: I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding what you're trying to achieve. Also what is `item.size` since Item class doesn't even have a size property. Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: Item has a property `Widget icon` which is of type Icon. I can change it to make it clearer.
I want to set all iconsizes in that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IconTheme` widget is what you probably want:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IconTheme-class.html

Comment: I wasn't that precise in my question, but in my examples. I want to set a global default, that can be overriden when a size for a child icon is provided. So I can't wrap my parent widget into an IconTheme, what I need to do is wrap every icon in an IconTheme. I don't know if this is more effective than my solution, but it works.

Comment: IconTheme will set options for all icons in its subtree, unless you insert another IconTheme in the subtree or explicitly set options on a specific icon.